# Accessing Amazon MWS using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, xml, amazon-web-services, google-apps-script, amazon-mws

I am somehow manage to write a code as per the documentation. But unfortunately it is not working. Below is the code, have a look, please let me know what im doing wrong or missing field. I have written this code by referring someone's code.

```
function test(){

  var date = new Date(); 
  var amz_date  = date.toISOString(); //2018-05-01T20:40:50.940Z

  var yearMonthDay= Utilities.formatDate(date, 'UTC', 'yyyyMMdd');
  var hourMinuteSec = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'UTC', 'HHmmss');

  var dateForStringToSign = yearMonthDay +'T'+hourMinuteSec+'Z'; //20180501T204050Z

  var datestamp = yearMonthDay; // 20180501

  var access_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var secret_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

  var method = 'POST';
  var host = 'mws.amazonservices.com';
  var endpoint = 'https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01';  
  var canonical_uri = '/Orders/2013-09-01';
  var canonical_querystring =  'AWSAccessKeyId='+encodeURIComponent('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
      canonical_querystring += '&Action='+encodeURIComponent('GetOrder');
      canonical_querystring += '&AmazonOrderId.Id.1='+encodeURIComponent('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
      canonical_querystring += '&MWSAuthToken='+encodeURIComponent('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
      canonical_querystring += '&SellerId='+encodeURIComponent('xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
      canonical_querystring += '&SignatureMethod='+encodeURIComponent('HmacSHA256');
      canonical_querystring += '&SignatureVersion='+encodeURIComponent('2');
      canonical_querystring += '&Timestamp='+encodeURIComponent(amz_date);
      canonical_querystring += '&Version='+encodeURIComponent('2013-09-01');


   //To construct the finished canonical request, combine all the components
   var finished_canonical= method + "\n"+host+"\n" +canonical_uri+ "\n" + canonical_querystring;

   //Calculate the Signature
   var signature=getSignature(finished_canonical,secret_key); 

   //Add signature to querystring
   canonical_querystring += '&Signature='+encodeURIComponent(signature);

   Logger.log(canonical_querystring);
   var request_url = endpoint + '?' + canonical_querystring;
   var options = {

      'method' : 'post',
      'muteHttpExceptions':true,
      'host': host,

   }
   var x = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request_url, options);
   Logger.log(x);
 }
```

Here is the Signature Generator function in GAS,

```
//Return Signatue (hash) from HmacSha256 
function getSignature(message,secret){
  var byteSignature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(message, secret);
  // convert byte array to hex string
  var signature = byteSignature.reduce(function(str,chr){
    chr = (chr < 0 ? chr + 256 : chr).toString(16);
    return str + (chr.length==1?'0':'') + chr;
  },'');
  return signature;
}
```

As you can see in the code, after generating the Signature, im appending it as a last parameter to the query string. Would that be a issue?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html

Comment: that is for AWS, not MWS

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

Read the section [here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_ClientLibraries.html) called "If you create your own client library".  It discusses formatting a url and signing.

Also, here is a link that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36417555/3047

Comment: It didn't worked out well, im getting Signature Mismatch error, if possible can you share your contact details i will show you the process, or you can msg me on twitter @Iamsidmish . Thanks buddy! Really im stuck